# Change file usage in Android Studio

Tags: android, file, android-studio

Is there a way to change the file usage in Android Studio? I have accidentally assigned a TTF file to an XML file and I can not reset even if I import the file again into the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may click on the resource and press shift + F6 to refactor and rename.

Or

you may do the old school way of right clicking on the resource and rename it

Or

you may manually go to the specified folder via Windows Explorer and rename  it

In all the three steps you may rename the file or it's extension

From Android Studio **Open Settings** and navigate to Editor and click on **FileTypes** and search for **Font** and you can find ttf or xml and change it to whatever you like

[image: Settings]
[image: Settings 1]

Comment: But Android Studio uses the same type for TTF even if I rename the file

Comment: Then I guess you need to it old school way, manually opening the file manager and renaming it.